# Why can I extend a Ruby class multiple times with require_relative?

Tags: ruby

Assume I have the following two files:

**app.rb**

```
class App
  def a
    "a"
  end
  require_relative 'b'
end
```

**b.rb**

```
class App
  def b
    "b"
  end
end
```

`App` in `app.rb` is being successfully extended by `App` in `b.rb`, but I have no idea why. Why does this work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
class App
  def a
    "a"
  end
end

class App
  def b
    "b"
  end
end
```

You might suppose it is equivalent to:

```
class App
  def a
    "a"
  end
  class App
    def b
      "b"
    end
  end
end
```

It isn't, because the `require`'d file code is always executed in a global scope.

Answer (score 0):

`require_relative` is pulling the code from b.rb into app.rb

Ruby is a dynamic language and allows you to open and close existing classes at will. Basically when you run app.rb, it reads method 'a' and then reads b.rb giving you access to method 'b' from the app.rb program.

Require_relative assumes the required file is in app.rb's root directory.

This becomes very useful in more complex situations when you might want to add methods to previouskly existing (Ruby Core) classes like Array.

Read this book for a more in depth understanding:
[Metaprogramming with Ruby](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476)